# Tap-And-Hold Event on ScatterViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I can't find infos on how to receive custom gestures on ScatterViewItems. I want "Tap-And-Hold" to invoke a function in the class behind my template.

Answer (score 0):

The following link is how to receive Touch Gestures Win32 messages using "WndProc" but the sample is in C++

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371578(v=vs.85).aspx

Another method is to actually implement a Tap-Hold gesture using a simple "DispatcherTimer" which should start when the "ScatterViewItem" is touched down in the "PreviewTouchDown" event handler of the element that you want to apply the gesture on.

```
void OnPreviewTouchDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
{
if(e.Source.GetHashCode() == YourUIElement.GetHashCode() )
{ 
MyTimer.Start();

//You need to capture the touch before the ScatterViewItem handles its own touch which will    
//block you from receiving the touch up event 
YourUIElement.CaptureTouch(e.TouchDevice);
e.Handled = true;

}
}

void OnPreviewTouchUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
{
YourUIElement.ReleaseAllTouches();
}


private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// To call whatever function or do whatever action you need.
IsTapHoldGestureOkay = true;
DoStuff();
MyTimer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TouchExtensions.AddTapGestureHandler(your_object_that_willdetect, your_handler_function);
```

a bit late but no harm =)